# Can tax treaty exemption be applied to spouse's income?

Tags: united-states, taxes, tax-exemption, china

I'm a green card holder and my wife is a F1 student from China, and we are filing our tax return jointly this year.

My wife doesn't have any income, and I wonder if we can still claim the $5,000 tax exemption under the US-China tax treaty article 20 since we file jointly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. As far as I know, that treaty provision only applies to the international student's income.